# How to clear cache on server side

Tags: rest, caching, spring-mvc

I am going to implement a RESTful service using Spring framework, and also use redis to cache some time stamped data. Because the data is time stamped, which means the data will expire some time later. My question is, how should I clear the expired data on redis? The solution I can think of now is to use a job scheduler such as cron to run another program for this purpose. But I am still wondering if there is any more efficient way for the need. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: post some code what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that redis has EXPIRE command, which can achieve what I need.
 [EXPIRE key seconds](http://redis.io/commands/expire)